# Create EC2 instance by Ansible with aws credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I followed these 3 guides:

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html
- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_module.html
- https://gist.github.com/tristanfisher/e5a306144a637dc739e7

and I wrote this Ansible play

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - include_vars: aws_credentials.yml
    - name: Creating EC2 Ubuntu instance
      ec2:
        instance_type: t1.micro
        image: ami-86e0ffe7
        region: us-west-2
        key_name: my-aws-key
        zone: us-west-2a
        vpc_subnet_id: subnet-04199d61
        group_id: sg-cf6736aa
        assign_public_ip: yes
        count: 1
        wait: true
        volumes:
          - device_name: /dev/sda1
            volume_type: gp2
            volume_size: 10
        instance_tags:
          Name: ansible-test
          Project: test
          Ansible: manageable

      register: ec2
```

then I run `ansible-playbook create-ec2.yml -v --private-key ~/.ssh/my-key --vault-password-file ~/.password/to_ansible_vault`

and I was getting this message

> PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
>
> TASK [include_vars] ************************************************************
>
> ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"ec2_access_key": "decrypted_acces_key_XXXXX", "ec2_secret_key": "decrypted_secret_key_XXXXX"}, "changed": false}
>
> TASK [Creating EC2 Ubuntu instance] ********************************************
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No handler was ready to authenticate. 1 handlers were checked. ['HmacAuthV4Handler'] Check your credentials"}
>
> NO MORE HOSTS LEFT  *************************************************************
>
> [WARNING]: Could not create retry file 'create-ec2.retry'.         [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
>
> PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
>
> localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

when I ran `ansible-vault view aws_credentials.yml --vault-password-file ~/.password/to_ansible_vault` I got readable content of encrypted aws_credentials.yml,
something like this :

```
---
ec2_access_key: "XXXXX"
ec2_secret_key: "XXXXX"
```

Also when I used plain aws_credentials.yml, it doesn't work. Only when I export my credentials, it works without any failure.
Could somebody help me, how can I write playbook for creating ec2 instance with credentials stored in encrypted file?

Comment: Ansible config generate from AWS http://8gwifi.org/aws.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should supply your keys directly to ec2 module in this case.
Try this:

```
   - name: Creating EC2 Ubuntu instance
      ec2:
        aws_access_key: "{{ ec2_access_key }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ ec2_secret_key }}"
        instance_type: t1.micro
        image: ami-86e0ffe7
        region: us-west-2
        ...
```

[The code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/ec2.py#L96) suggests that it only checks module's arguments and environment variables, not host variables.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can export your AWS API keys to OS environment variables, like a:
`export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXXX`

In that case in Ansible scenario you need to set: 
    `- name: Creating EC2 Ubuntu instance
      ec2:
        aws_access_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY') }}"
        aws_secret_key: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_SECRET_KEY') }}"
        instance_type: t1.micro
        image: ami-86e0ffe7
        region: us-west-2`